Blogger blogs are not getting indexed by Google
I have created lots of blogs via Blogger and deployed them on my paid domain, but after 2 years I switched to the free domain (2 years ago), for example: https://example.blogspot.com/ after using this free domain, my blogs are not getting indexed by Google. In Google Search Console, I can see the below report.

I am not sure what is the issue. Please help.
Below are some blogs which are not indexed:


How long have you waited?  Were the old URLs redirected?  Can you give an example of a specific page you expect to be indexed but is not indexed?

@RichardB it appears he switched 2 years ago.

@RichardB I switched two years back. I have attached images of blogs that are not indexed. This is one example https://swatiguptablogs.blogspot.com/2019/06/create-sitecore-custom-admin-page.html. How I can redirect old URL to new URL?

The specific page you mentioned is probably not being indexed its because it's an exact copy of a page on another site (websparks.sg/create-sitecore-custom-admin-page).
With the other pages, my best guess is that without many decent backlinks, Google may be assuming that a free Blogspot page is likely to be spam (your backlinks tend to mostly be cloned pages hosted on websparks).  Also, your navigation is poor (the hamburger menu is empty, for example), so the site is not very crawlable.
You can never know for sure with Google, but it seems that you need a few more signifiers that your site isn't spam/junk before they'll bother indexing a Blogspot page.  Ultimately, your own domain name is one way to show that it's less likely to be spam.

websparks is using only few blogs so I don't think so that could be a reason. Is there any way to index my free website?

Decent backlinks from relevant sites that aren't hosted on free hosting is your best bet.
You've got to signal that your site hosted on free hosting has some quality to it.

It's not you, it's Blogger. All bloggers are facing this issue after Google started using Googlebot smartphone to crawl pages. Blogger appends the ?m=1 parameter to your urls to optimize them for mobile view but that created a problem for the crawlers. When you submit the desktop url for indexing, say, https://example.blogspot.com/2024-09/html, the crawler used first is the smartphone crawler (Googlebot smartphone). When it tries to crawler this url, it gets redirected to the mobile url which is https://example.blogspot.com/2024-09/html?m=1. The bot gets confused and returns a "redirect error" because Blogger also generates the canonical url which points to the desktop url. Ideally, this should be resolved within a few days...or weeks when the desktop bot (Googlebot desktop) crawls that same desktop url. However, although both bots eventually crawl your site, the issue does not seem to resolve and this has pissed me and a lot of bloggers. I will move to WordPress soon.
